# Apple Pay, Payment Not Complete Web JS

Tags: applepay, applepayjs

I have followed the documentation on apple website regarding apple pay.

onValidateMerchant and completeMerchantValidation work perfectly but right after that it jumps to oncancel.

I have messages at are printed to the screen within onpaymentselected and onpaymentauthorized but they are never printed.

I have added a try catch to catch any errors that pop, turns out onpaymentselect and onpaymentauthorized are run before onValidateMerchant and completeMerchantValidation.

```
applePayButton.addEventListener("click", function(){

const request = {
    countryCode: 'US',
    currencyCode: 'USD',
    merchantCapabilities: [
        'supports3DS'
    ],
    supportedNetworks: [
        'visa',
        'masterCard',
        'amex',
        'discover'
    ],
    lineItems: [{
            label: 'Amount',
            amount: 0.95,
        },
        {
            label: 'Tax',
            amount: 0.05,
        }
    ],
    total: {
        label: 'Total',
        amount: 10,
    }
};
var session = new ApplePaySession(10, request);
session.begin();

try{
    session.onvalidatemerchant = function(event){
        printMessage("starting session.onvalidatemerchant" + JSON.stringify(event));

        var promise = performValidation(event.validationURL);

        promise.then(function(merchantSession) {
            printMessage("Merchant Session: "+ JSON.stringify(merchantSession));
            session.completeMerchantValidation(merchantSession);
        });
    }
}
catch(error){
    printMessage("On Validate Merchant Error: " + error)
}

try{
    printMessage("onpaymentmethodselected");

    session.onpaymentmethodselected = function(event) {
        printMessage("In On Payment Method Selected");
        //var myPaymentMethod = event.paymentMethod;

        const update = {};
        session.completePaymentMethodSelection(update);
    };

}
catch(error){
    printMessage("On Payment Method Selected Error: " + error)
}

try{
    printMessage("onpaymentauthorized");
    session.onpaymentauthorized = function(event) {
        printMessage("starting session.onpaymentauthorized");

        var applePaymentToken = event.payment.token;

        printMessage("Token" + applePaymentToken);

        // Define ApplePayPaymentAuthorizationResult
        session.completePayment(session.STATUS_SUCCESS);
    };

}
catch(error){
    printMessage("On Payment Authorized Error: " + error)
}

try{
    session.oncancel = function(event) {
        printMessage("starting session.oncancel" + JSON.stringify(event));

        // Payment cancelled by WebKit
    };
}
catch(error){
    printMessage("On Cancel Error: " + error)
}
```

});

This is the message that comes after payment Not Complete

Session:
Step 1: applePay working

Step 2: onpaymentmethodselected

Step 3: onpaymentauthorized

Step 4: starting session.onvalidatemerchant{"isTrusted":true}

Step 5: Complete Merchant Validation:

Step 6: starting session.oncancel{"isTrusted":true}

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where the payment sheet would display then go away without a chance to authorize the transaction. I made sure the domain was verified, the certificate was valid, and that I was actually receiving a response back from the server side request to Apple. Sorting through the process of elimination I came across certain interesting observations:

- If the payment sheet disappeared immediately, it was usually due to a configuration issue with the server side request payload (for example, the "initiativeContext" was "something.com" when I was actually using "www.something.com" in the web browser address).
- If the payment sheet disappeared after several seconds, it was usually due to a syntax issue or error in the client side JavaScript. In my case, I was not doing session.onpaymentmethodselected and session.completepaymentmethodselection correctly. So I removed all other Apple specific JS functions except for session.onvalidatemerchant and a subsequent call to session.completeMerchantValidation passing the Apple response from the server side request. It then worked.
- If the Apple response from the server side request was in any way (even just the casing) changed from what Apple originally sent it would not work (for instance, "epochtimestamp":1668095263534," vs "epochTimestamp":1668095263534,").

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it seems that when the `onvalidatemerchant` fails with this `{"isTrusted":true}` is because:

- You don't have `fingerprint` enabled, or
- You're not using `Safari`, or
- Your call to `validate` on the backend is wrong somehow

If these parts are working, then you should see the Apple Pay modal and should be able to make everything work (hopefully)

Comment: The issue I had was in the backend when I was sending my website link I was sending it as 'example.com' and it should be 'www.example.com' :)

Comment: They should have some sort of error message to show that something was wrong. These smoke errors aren't helpful at all

Answer (score 0):

Problem we ran into is that we weren’t rounding to 2 decimal points. Apple Pay wasn’t happy with `4.435` for example, instead wants `4.44` for the amount.